# EE Store: Add csv file to order confirmation email

Tags: expresso-store

LS
I would like to add a csv file to the order confirmation email containing fields from the order.

Like so:

Header:
Type verzending ; Familienaam ; Adres 1 ;land ; Postcode ; Woonplaats ; Vooraanmeldingstype 1 ; Contactgegevens 1 ; Proactive rule 1 ; Pro-active taalinstelling 1

Rule:
NCP,PRO;None;Test;NL;3145ER;Woerden;email;bvanzandvoort@gmail.com;1;NL

•   Type verzending: always "NCP,PRO"
•   Familienaam: {shipping_name}
•   Adres 1: {shipping_address1}
•   Land: {shipping_country}
•   Postcode: {shipping_postcode}
•   Woonplaats {shipping_city}
•   Vooraanmeldingstype 1: always "email"
•   Contactgegevens 1: {order_email}
•   Proactive rule 1: always "1"
•   Pro-active taalinstelling 1 : always "NL"

Is there anyway to add this as CSV file (or txt) as an attachment to the confirmation email?

Comment: I think it would be easier to include a link to a CSV file rather than attach it.

Comment: it needs to contain order specific data in order to print a distribution label

Comment: yes i can see that but all you have to do is create a template that generates the CSV and in your email, you set a link to that template that contains the order ID number. Then the template pulls that order info and generates a CSV that you can force to download. I've not used expresso-store but if the data is stored in EE you can do this. I know you can do it with CartThrob.

Comment: I think you just solved a headbreaker here thank you so much i will let you know if this solves my issue, thx!!

Comment: but wait, how do i make the template "be a csv file"?

Comment: A.U.B. als je meer nodig heb, ik ben op zoek voor meer werk! ; ]

Comment: use the http_header component

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to include a link to a CSV file rather than attach it.

All you have to do is create a template that generates the CSV and in your email, you set a link to that template that contains the order ID number. Then the template pulls that order info and generates a CSV that you can force to download. I've not used expresso-store but if the data is stored in EE you can do this. I know you can do it with CartThrob.

to generate the CSV you can use http_header component then you template looks something like this:

> {exp:http_header content_disposition="attachment"
>   content_type="text/csv" filename="{current_time
>   format="%y_%m_%d"}-members.csv"}ID,Status,Last name,First
>   name,Email,Last Payment,Join Date {exp:user:users
>   orderby="total_entries" sort="desc" dynamic_parameters="no"
>   limit="500" }{member_id},{if group_id == 4}Pending,{/if}{if group_id
>   == 6}BO Member,{/if}{if group_id == 7}Expired,{/if}{if group_id == 8}Content Admin,{/if}{if group_id == 9}Order Admin,{/if}{if group_id
>   == 1}Admin,{/if}{if group_id == 5}Expired,{/if}{if group_id == 10}Member
>   Admin,{/if}{last_name},{first_name},{email},{payment},{join_date
>   format="%m/%d/%y"} {/exp:user:users}

Comment: completely agree.  Its the same principle as having a download invoice link. I'll add that if you want to render the CSV links unreadable, you can store a hash value with your order ( in a custom field) and use that hash id to pull the info you need.